# 2 Mayors in a city...how to score?

Tags: carcassonne

We just finished playing a 2 person game of Carcassonne with the Abbey and Mayor expansion. We ended up with both mayors in one city. One of us was able to bring in an additional meeple. Does that one meeple break a tie in a huge city with multiple pennants? I know we can’t put two mayors in one city, but if they’re joined together it gets tricky. How does this city end up scoring?

Answer (score 4):

If player one has a meeple and a mayor and player two has just a mayor, then player one will win, as player one will have `N + 1` strength vs player two's `N` strength, where N is the number of coat of arms (i.e. pennants) in the city.

From the rules:

> The strength of your mayor is equal to the number of coats of arms in the city it occupies. If two or more players have meeples in the same city, it is scored as follows:
>
> ●Each normal meeple has 1 strength.
>
> ●Each large meeple has 2 strength.
>
> ●Each mayor has strength equal to the number of coats of arms in the city. If there are no coats of arms, the mayor has 0 strength.
>
> When scoring a city, each player adds the strength of their meeples in the city. The player with the highest strength scores the points for that city. In case of a tie, all tied players score full points.

Note that "coat of arms" is the 2014 rules term for "pennant".  See [When was "pennant" renamed "coat of arms" in Carcassonne?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/53829/9999) for more.

Answer (score 1):

From the "Abbey and Mayor" rules

> Each mayor has strength equal to the number of coats of arms in the city.

so if player A had 1 mayor in a completed city and player B has 1 mayor and 1 meeple the size of the city and number of shields is irrelevant.

Player B has one more strength and score all the points for that city.